# Custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift3, cell

I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to create custom tableViewCells but I've got a problem. I have 3 sections for my tableViewCell and an Array.When I try to assign values to cells at `UITableView, cellForRowAt` it start the array from the top for each section.
Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct cellData {

let cell : Int!
let text : String!
}

class SettingsTableViewCell : UITableViewController{

 var arrayOfCellData = [cellData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    arrayOfCellData = [cellData(cell : 1, text : "تغییر رنگ دکمه تنظیمات"),
                       cellData(cell : 2, text : "تغییر تصویر پشت زمینه"),
                       cellData(cell : 1, text : "تغییر رنگ قلم"),
                       cellData(cell : 2, text : "اعلانات"),
                       cellData(cell : 2, text : "صداها"),
                       cellData(cell : 2, text : "زبان"),
                       cellData(cell : 2, text : "بازگشت به حالت پیش فرض"),
                       cellData(cell : 2, text : "سوالات متداول")]


}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0{
        return 3
    }
    else if section == 1{
         return 4
    }
    else if section == 2{

        return 1
    }


    return arrayOfCellData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 1{


        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell_Type1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell_Type1

        cell.cellName_1.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell

    }
    else if arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 2{

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell_Type2", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell_Type2

        cell.cellName_2.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell


    }
    else{

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell_Type1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell_Type1

        cell.cellName_1.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell


    }



}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {



    if section == 0{
        return "تنظیمات رنگ\n"
    }
    else if section == 1{
        return "تنظیمات سیستم\n"
    }
    else if section == 2{

        return "پشتیبانی\n"
    }

    return ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use old ways of coding like "Bundle.main.loadNibNamed", instead use "registerNib" that will help you in creating the cells. Also, can you post the screen shot of your problem?

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are considering only the row of the index path. Therefore each section displays the same objects from the top of the array. Further you can design multiple custom cells in Interface Builder (I guess since Xcode 6), there is no need for extra nibs. And finally don't hard-code `numberOfRows`. Create an appropriate model with nested arrays or something else to use always the `count` property.

Comment: You can't just consider `indexPath.row`, calculate the array index based on  `indexPath.section` and  `indexPath.row`. Then you will get exact element from array.

Comment: @NikhilManapure Could you please help me more?

Comment: int index = 0;
if section == 0{
    index = indexPath.row}
else if section == 1{
    index = indexPath.row + 3
}
else if section == 2{
    index = indexPath.row + 3 + 4
}
Use this index for arrayOfCellData[index].text

Comment: Same thing as given in Gabriel's answer.

Comment: This episode of Swift Talk discusses multiple cell types in one `tableView`. It is subscription only, so unfortunately I cannot share any details, but it might be worthwhile to check it out. https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E26-generic-table-view-controllers-part-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code this way, and it worked!

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var offset = 0

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        offset = 0

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        offset = 3

    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {

        offset = 7

    }


    if arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row + offset].cell == 1 {


        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell_Type1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell_Type1

        cell.cellName_1.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row + offset].text

        return cell

    }
    else if arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row + offset].cell == 2 {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell_Type2", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell_Type2

        cell.cellName_2.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row + offset].text

        return cell


    }
    else {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell_Type1", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell_Type1

        cell.cellName_1.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row + offset].text

        return cell

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion with a more convenient data source

- Create an enum for the cell types

  ```
  enum CellType {
      case one, two
  }
  ```
- The `CellData` struct contains the title for the sections, an array for the cell types and an array for the text strings.

  ```
  struct CellData {
      let title : String
      let typeArray : [CellType]
      let textArray : [String]
  }
  ```
- Declare the data source array

  ```
  var arrayOfCellData = [CellData]()
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` create the 3 sections. I apologize for using western text for the `textArray` items, because I got too confused about the right to left text behavior).

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let section0 = CellData(title: "تنظیمات رنگ\n", typeArray: [.one, .two, .one], textArray: ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"])
      let section1 = CellData(title: "تنظیمات سیستم\n", typeArray: [.two, .two, .two, .two], textArray: ["Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6", "Text 7"])
      let section2 = CellData(title: "پشتیبانی\n", typeArray: [.two], textArray: ["Text 8"])

      arrayOfCellData = [section0, section1, section2]
  }
  ```

Now the data source and delegate methods are much easier to populate.
The following code assumes that both cells are designed **directly** in Interface Builder with custom classes named `TableViewCell_Type1` and `TableViewCell_Type2` and appropriate identifiers `Type1` and `Type2`:

```
   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrayOfCellData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let section = arrayOfCellData[section]
        return section.textArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let section = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.section]
        let text = section.textArray[indexPath.row]
        let cellType = section.typeArray[indexPath.row]


        switch cellType {
        case .one:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Type1", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell_Type1
            cell.cellName_1.text = text
            return cell

        case .two:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Type2", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell_Type2
            cell.cellName_2.text = text
            return cell

        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        let section = arrayOfCellData[section]
        return section.title
    }
```

Comment: Your answer has `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Her's doesn't! Is there any way that it can even work without such?!

Comment: I deliberately wrote the code for resusable cells, because it's much easier to implement. Unfortunately many many tutorials suggest the more cumbersome (and ancient) way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row], try this to calculate correct index in array:

```
   var idx = indexPath.row
   if indexPath.section == 1 { idx += 3 }
   else if indexPath.section == 2 { idx += 7 }

   // and then you can use:
   arrayOfCellData[idx]
```

Comment: After using your solution I've got a compiler error. It complain with this error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'section.Type' and 'Int'

Comment: @fatemeh when ever you want to use `==` you should use it on 2 values that have the same type. I don't know what `section.Type` is, but `Int` is obviously an integer. So be sure what you compare are of the same type. You can always `Ctrl + click` on a variable to see its type. fahmidin?

Comment: @fatemeh section is indexPath.section. I thought it is obvious. I have edited the code.

Comment: @Honey yeah sure. fahmidam honey :-D